# Does an app have the privilege to turn off all notifications in OSX?

Tags: ios, macos, ios8, osx-mavericks, elevated-privileges

Can app have the privilege to turn off all (visual and sound) notifications in OSX. Im talking about all notifications...... native and non-native notifications. Im looking to create a distraction-free environment for the user. Also is this privilege available in IOS 8??

Comment: Definitely not in iOS 8, or any version of iOS for that matter

Comment: What about only disabling SOUND notifications from an app in iOS 8.

Comment: The user can set DND mode or mute the device. I am not sure what the effect of your app setting the volume to 0 is

Comment: So DND mode can only be set from iOS settings? I need this app to set DND mode to many devices at once(OSX,IOS,Android).

Comment: On iOS the user is in control of their device, not an app so you can't set DND.